# Calling Methods forom another File in C#

Tags: c#, console

First things first: I know that there are some questions that are similar to mine. I have been reading them and trying the code provided, but so far nothing worked or I simply didn't do it right. So that is why I decided to ask in the end. I am really sorry about that, but I don't know who else could help me otherwise.

So, what is the problem? I am currently working on a text based adventure game in my free time and the code simply got to big. I had everything packed in one file and decided to make another one, where I would store the Text of the story. Now I want to call the methods I stored in the Text file into the Adventure file. This is how I am trying to do it.

The text file looks like this. Of course there are multiple methods in the file.

```
using System;

namespace TextFile1
{
    public class GameText
    {
        public static string firstChapter()
        {
         ... some code ...
        }
```

And I have been trying to call it in the Adventure file like so.

```
namespace AdventureGame
{
    class Adventure
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // I am telling the player what he/she is going to experience in the game itself.
            TextCaller_1();
        }

        public static void TextCaller_1();
        {
            TextFile1.GameText.firstChapter();
        }
    }
}
```

I have read somewhere, that you should create a separate method to call the methods from another file. Another one would be to create another class within the main file and create the references there. Something like this:

```
public class Adventure
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // I am telling the player what he/she is going to experience in the game itself.
            TextCaller_1();
        }
}

public class Adventure_2
{
   public void TextCaller_1()
   {
      Adventure adventure = new Adventure();
      adventure.TextCaller_1();
   }
}
```

This however throws me some errors and no matter what I did, it would not let me call the methods. I should probably say, that I am a novice programmer and just recently got into this entire thing.

Once again, I am really sorry for the question and I assure you I have looked far and wide but I don't seem to be able to make this ting work whatsoever. Every help/explanation on what I did wrong and how I can fix it is much appreciated.

Thanks for your help folks.

Comment: You should just pick up a tutorial and start from the basics, maybe creating something step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to use "using" if another file is from another namespace
2. Method "TextCaller_1" belongs to class "Adventure_2", so you could not find method "TextCaller_1" from class "Adventure".

Here is the sample code:

----- Game Text.cs -----

```
using System;

namespace TextFile1
{
    public class GameText
    {
        public static string firstChapter()
        {
            ... some code ...
        }
    }
}
```

----- Adventure.cs -----

```
using TextFile1;

namespace AdventureGame
{
    class Adventure
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // I am telling the player what he/she is going to experience in the game itself.
            TextCaller_1();
        }

        public static void TextCaller_1();
        {
            // You need to initialize an object here
            GameText gameText = new GameText();
            // then call one of its methods
            string text = gameText.firstChapter();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It really helped me out. I owe you one.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when working on a multi-file project in C#, you just create a solution.

Using an IDE like Visual Studio will allow you to add/remove classes and files, reference them easily and see what is wrong with the code you're writing.